# pipenv 使用環境で gunicorn を自動起動するための Systemd ユニットファイルをどう記述すれば良いですか？

Tags: python, ubuntu, django, systemd, pipenv

現在、DjangoをさくらVPSにデプロイしようとしており、下記サイトを参考にしているのですが、このサイトの環境と私の環境で違う点は私はvenvではなくpipenvを使用している点です。

[さくらの VPS (Ubuntu 20.04) で Django アプリを作る](https://notemite.com/django/sakura-vps-django-02/#web-server)

gunicornを自動化する為にsystemdの中で.socketと.serviceを作りました。
そこで問題が起きました。pipenvではbinフォルダがないため、記事にある.serviceと同じようにExecStartを書くことができません。
pipenvを使用している場合の.serviceの書き方を教えてください。

現状、Error: the command gunicorn could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].
とエラーが出ます。

追記：　statusを確認するとこのような結果が表示されます。

```
● sample.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sample.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-07-16 12:42:38 JST; 4s ago
TriggeredBy: ● sample.socket
    Process: 57015 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/sample.sock config.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAIL>
   Main PID: 57015 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 7月 16 12:42:37 tk2-117-59435 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
 7月 16 12:42:38 tk2-117-59435 pipenv[57015]: Error: the command gunicorn could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].
 7月 16 12:42:38 tk2-117-59435 systemd[1]: sample.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 7月 16 12:42:38 tk2-117-59435 systemd[1]: sample.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

また.serviceと.socketの内容以下の通りです。

sample.service

```
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=sample.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/sample.com/html/MyApp
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run gunicorn --access-logfile -  --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/sample.sock config.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sample.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/sample.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
~
```

**環境:**
Django 3.2
Python 3.8
pipenv
gunicorn
nginx
ubuntu

Comment: gunicorn を自分自身が手動で起動する際はどのようなコマンドを実行していますか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。申し訳ありません。まだ試せてはいないのですが多分　gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi:application  と打つのかなと思っています。現在、venv環境の直下にpipenvを入れたのですが、コレはやめた方がやめた方がいいですかね？別の質問をしてしまって申し訳ありません。

Comment: つい9日前に出た/更新された?らしい資料のようですが、もしかしたら参考になるかも。[singerng/Django_Default_Config.md](https://gist.github.com/singerng/ebbcc4c09fdb58cfce3f6000635cc46d)

Comment: .serviceに関してはほぼこの通りに書いたんですけど、statusを確認すると、Error: the command gunicorn could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].と出てしまうんですよね。あと気になる点がありまして、.serviceの[Service]ってrootでいいんですか？ここも原因の一つだったりしませんかね

Comment: 他にはこんな記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。[gunicorn + Flask + nginx + Systemdで動かしてみた](https://qiita.com/arata-honda/items/09e1c350b1bd8a186e9c), [pipenv で作ったプログラムを systemd でデーモン化する](https://blog.cles.jp/item/12191) あるいはこの辺の記事 [How to Deploy Django App on Cloud Raya VM Using Gunicorn, Supervisor, and Nginx](https://cloudraya.com/knowledge-base/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-cloud-raya-vm-using-gunicorn-supervisor-and-nginx/), [Global gunicorn and pipenv virtual env: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60744507/9014308) から推測すると、`gunicorn`を`pipenv`でinstallしたかどうか？かも。